# Count Number of Instances in JSON File

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on some JSON parsing code, and I wanted to check if there are multiple "Addresses" blocks. In my example  below there would be addresses[0] and addresses[1].

I could obviously just go by checking if I specifically want "LOCATION" or "MAILING", but is there a way to do something like

```
if address.length() > 1
```

or something along those lines?

```
"addresses" : [
    {
      "country_code" : "",
      "country_name" : "",
      "address_purpose" : "LOCATION",
      "address_type" : "",
      "address_1" : "",
      "address_2" : "",
      "city" : "",
      "state" : "",
      "postal_code" : "",
      "telephone_number" : "",
      "fax_number" : ""
    },
    {
      "country_code" : "",
      "country_name" : "",
      "address_purpose" : "MAILING",
      "address_type" : "",
      "address_1" : "",
      "address_2" : "",
      "city" : "",
      "state" : "",
      "postal_code" : "",
      "telephone_number" : "",
      "fax_number" : ""
    }
  ],
```

Comment: `foo.bar.blah.baz.addresses.length` will work

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since its an array you can indeed check the length of it:

```js
let obj = {"addresses" : [
    {
      "country_code" : "",
      "country_name" : "",
      "address_purpose" : "LOCATION",
      "address_type" : "",
      "address_1" : "",
      "address_2" : "",
      "city" : "",
      "state" : "",
      "postal_code" : "",
      "telephone_number" : "",
      "fax_number" : ""
    },
    {
      "country_code" : "",
      "country_name" : "",
      "address_purpose" : "MAILING",
      "address_type" : "",
      "address_1" : "",
      "address_2" : "",
      "city" : "",
      "state" : "",
      "postal_code" : "",
      "telephone_number" : "",
      "fax_number" : ""
    }
  ]}

console.log(obj.addresses.length > 1)
```

Comment: The whole JSON file has more sections than just the addresses, I just didn't include the entire thing in my original question. Would this still work in that case?

Comment: yes if because you target the adresses by calling `.addresses`

Comment: So I have my whole JSON message stored in a variable named "msg". When trying msg.addresses.length > 1 I get a "Cannot call method "length" of undefined" error

Comment: Might be a good idea then to just include your whole object in your question because it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a data format, Javascript can parse it with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and create a JS object out of it.

Then, depending on how your object is structured, you can apply/call any method on it, including `array.length`